# How to update ngModel along with the click event in Angular 6

Tags: angular, primeng

I cannot create a stackblitz because I'm using a 3rd party component library which is not open source. I'm using a multiselect component from that lib which is very much similar to multiselect component of primeng.

Here's the HTML:

```
<lib-multiselect [(ngModel)]="fruit" name="fruit" modelChange="multiselectModelChange">
    <lib-multiselect-option (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)" *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [value]="fruit">
        <span>{{ fruit?.name }}</span>&nbsp;
    </lib-multiselect-option>
</lib-multiselect>
```

**Typescript**

```
public fruits = [
    {name: 'Apple'},
    {name: 'Pear'},
    {name: 'Melon'},
    {name: 'Orange'},
    {name: 'Banana'}
];

public fruit = [
   
];

onSelectionChange(e) {
    console.log(this.fruit);
}
```

My problem is that it is printing one step behind. I mean when I select 1st option, the array `fruit` is blank but when I select 2nd option i.e. Pear then the array contains `Apple`, this means when I select 3rd option i.e. Melon then the array contains ["Apple","Pear"]. Why it is always one step behind. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake by using `Event` on options.

> You can't bind event on the `options` add it to the parent which has
> `ngModel`.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="sample" (change)="handler()" multiple>
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In above sample we create an multiple select option and use `change` event directly on it.